# How to pass multi choice(checkbox) values in a caml query to fetch item from sharepoint list in o365

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query

Below is my code:

```
SP.ListItem listItem = null;
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();

camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View><Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name=" + field.InternalName + @"/><Value Type=" + field.TypeAsString + @">" + value + @"</Value></BeginsWith></Where></Query></View>";     

     SP.ListItemCollection items = selectedList.GetItems(camlQuery);
     clientContext.Load<SP.ListItemCollection>(items);
     clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
      if (items.Count > 0)
        listItem = items[0];

     return listItem;
```

It works fine for multi choice(radio button and dropdown) as it has single value in my SharePoint list choice column and I pass the single value and get the list item, but my code does not return any list item when my multi choice column is a check box and has multiple values in the choice column and when I pass that multiple values to fetch list item. Please suggest.

Comment: my caml query :camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View><Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name=" + field.InternalName + @"/><Value Type=" + field.TypeAsString + @">" + value + @"</Value></BeginsWith></Where></Query></View>";

Comment: Like I have A B and C as options. and in my list column I have B,C as value. Now how do I pass this B,C in caml query to get the list item.